# Apex - set items values after submit

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have to regions with items on my page. One of them is to edit data, another one is display only. Editable region is hidden on page load and shows when users click on a button. I'd like to pass data between these regions after submit a page. Are computations after submit  the only way to do that? I tried with processes after submit, before header etc. but it didn't work.

I'd like to have one pl/sql code to pass data between two regions after submit, how to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

Other options include

- dynamic action (you'd use **Set value**)
- button's **Redirect to page in this application** (where you'd redirect to the same page; Link Builder then lets you choose which items will be set to which values)

If you still can't make it work, consider creating sample page on apex.oracle.com; then provide login credentials so that someone might have a look.

Comment: Actually, redirect to the same page in the application could be a good solution but I'd like to keep code in one place. Is it any way to achieve it via processes not a DA?